# How do I unbind a DocumentComplete Handler?

Tags: c#, html, events, browser

I have following code:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(Action1);
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(Action2);
```

Works just fine.

But they seem to trigger every time any page is done downloading.
Though I want them to trigger only once for every page.
Say Action1 for Page1, Action2 for Page2 etc.

I tried to add an empty handler like this:

```
void StopDoingStuff(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

But it seems that C# triggers this as a third handler for DocumentComplete event, so it does not actually stop other two.

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? This isn't how events work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To unsubscribe from an event, use the following syntax:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= Action2
```

Here's an msdn explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768(v=VS.100).aspx